# How to insert derived attribute in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, insert

i have two tables 1 table is student table with (sid,dob,address) another table is details where the attributes are (sid, age, marks) now while inserting into details table i want to get the age derived automatically from student table (dob) without entering  how can i do this

Answer (score 2):

You can insert the result of a select:

```
insert into details(sid, age)
    select sid, datediff(current_date, dob)
        from student
        where sid = 123
```

Comment: where do i enter the table name details

Comment: @user1275375 I mistakenly named the table `attributes` instead of `details`. I edited to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the age as follows:

```
select to_days(now())/365-to_days('1991-08-21')/365;
```

or

```
select period_diff(date_format(now(),'%Y%m'),199108)/12;
```